# Ubuntu 12.04 Wireless hotspot: Android stuck on obtaining ip address

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, adhoc

I recently upgraded to 12.04 and was delighted to find a simple button to start a wireless hotspot in Settings > Networks.

This is all well and good, however when I try and connect my android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab rooted with Ad-hoc support) the tablet gets stuck obtaining an IP address. It times out and then tries again to reconnect ad infinitum. I don't have this problem with Windows XP/Vista/7 (tried on all three) using ad hoc or connectify. I would use my windows 7 starter netbook to create my wireless hotspot, but unfortunately it died a terrible death.

Why is the android unable to obtain an IP address? How can I fix this? Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server set up? Or can you try using a manual IP on Android?

Comment: I thought that Ubuntu would autoomatically act as a DHCP server and  assign an IP address?

Comment: Update: Once a windows machine is connected the Android connects, but none of them are able to access  the internet. I live in student accommodation which only allows 1 computer to be registered to the network. The ubuntu laptop is the one registered.

Comment: You may want to manually install a DHCP server set to listening on your ad-hoc connection.

Comment: hostapd/firestater/how do I go about this?

Comment: @Fayaaz: The reason that neither one can connect is because the university has it configured that way. It's a common thing, they do packet inspection and check the number of hops it takes. Nothing you can do technically to get around it, sorry. :(